# Make one function accept parameters from the other

Tags: javascript, function, object, methods, constructor

**I have this task:**

*Write constructor functions that create objects representing students - they are to include first name, last name, index number, table with grades and a method that prints first name, surname and grade average. Use it to create an object that represents yourself.*

So from my understanding, I need to create two constructor functions: one should be a functions accepting parameters for the grades from specific subject and calculate the average grade from a specific grade set of a specific student.

I'm trying to understand how to pas something like this

```
function Grade(math, compsc, sc){
    this.math = math;
    this.compcs = compsc;
    this.sc = sc;
}
```

Into something like this (or make it reference it, or somehow to pass the arguments of those predefined grade parameters values into this function)

```
function Student(index, first, last, grade) {
    this.indexNum = index;
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
    this.grade = grade;
    this.gradeAvg = function gradeAvg() {
        let total = 0;
        for (let value in this.grade) {
          total += this.grade[value]
        }
        return total / Object.entries(this.grade).length;
    };
    this.outPrint = function outPrint() {
        console.log("Student number: " + JSON.stringify(this.indexNum) + "\n First name: " + this.firstName + "\n Last name: " + this.lastName + "\n Grades: \n Math:" + this.grade.math + "\n compcs:"+ this.grade.compcs + "\n sc:" + this.grade.sc + "\n average grade:"+ this.gradeAvg())
    }
}
```

Ideally, it would be something like this but a working one:

```
function Student(index, first, last, grade) {
    this.indexNum = index;
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
    grade = function(math, copcsc, sc){
        this.math = math;
        this.compsc = compcs;
        this.sc = sc;
    };
    this.gradeAvg = function gradeAvg() {
        let total = 0;
        for (let value in this.grade) {
          total += this.grade[value]
        }
        return total / Object.entries(this.grade).length;
    };
    this.outPrint = function outPrint() {
        console.log("Student number: " + JSON.stringify(this.indexNum) + "\n First name: " + this.firstName + "\n Last name: " + this.lastName + "\n Grades: \n Math:" + this.grade.math + "\n compcs:"+ this.grade.compcs + "\n sc:" + this.grade.sc + "\n average grade:"+ this.gradeAvg())
    }
}
```

and then initialization

```
    const me = new Student (345345, 'jora', 'orlovskiy',{math:10, compcs: 10, sc: 5})
console.log(me.outPrint());
```

and with the grade

```
const meGr = new grade(2,2,2)
```

I understand that my mistake may be a stupid one with syntaxes or with understanding the basic concepts. Maybe the initialization is wrong but I tried everythingg to make it work in different ways, but nothing helped, would appreciate any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your original version of `Student()`.

Then call `new Grade()` in the arguments to `new Student()`.

```
const me = new Student (345345, 'jora', 'orlovskiy', new Grade(10, 10, 5));
```